# Conditional Interval Integration

Tags: grafana, graphite

I have Grafana setup to graph sparse, binary timeseries data in graphite format about tool usage in a plugin. I'd like to be able to design a metric that is similar to `integralByInterval` but where the interval is based on time since that metric last received a datapoint. i.e.

for time `t` if the interval limit is `10m`

```
the-interesting-metric.endpoint 1 (t)
the-interesting-metric.endpoint 1 (t+9.99m)
the-interesting-metric.endpoint 1 (t+19.99m)
```

sums to `3`

```
the-interesting-metric.endpoint 1 (t)
the-interesting-metric.endpoint 1 (t+10.01m)
the-interesting-metric.endpoint 1 (t+20.02m)
```

shows 3 hits of `1`

Does this exist or is it possible to construct?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [smartSummarize](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.smartSummarize)`(the-interesting-metric.endpoint, "10m", "sum")`

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell if that's exactly right, but I think it's more due to my data right now, so I'll accept it. Thanks!